# Use of implication vs. such that.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, predicate-logic

Given any two rational numbers $a$ and $b$, it follows that $ab$ is rational.

$\forall$$a$,$b$ $s.t.$ (($a$,$b$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Q}$) $\implies$ ($a$$b$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Q}$))

But I've seen it written:

$\forall$$a$,$b$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Q}$ $s.t.$ ($a$$b$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Q}$)

Comment: "such that" is not needed in formulas (and also ":" is superfluous) : The syntax is : $\forall x \in \mathbb Q \ (P(x))$ that is simply an abbreviation for : $\forall x \ (x \in \mathbb Q \to P(x))$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second reads as "for all rational $a$ and $b$ **such that** $ab$ is rational". Obviously this does not parse well, and for the same reason, I would argue the first one is flawed too.

Here are two standard alternatives:
$$
\forall a,b\left[\left(\left(a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\right)\implies\left(ab\in\mathbb{Q}\right)\right)\right]
\hspace{4em}\text{or}\hspace{4em}
\forall a,b\in \mathbb{Q}\left[ ab\in\mathbb{Q}\right].
$$

Comment: Could one use a comma instead? ∀a,b, ((a,b∈ℚ)⟹(ab∈ℚ)) or ∀a,b∈ℚ, ab∈ℚ

Comment: Is there anything wrong with $a,b\in\Bbb Q\implies ab\in\Bbb Q$?

Comment: I wouldn't think so, in the sentence $a, b \in \mathbb{Q} \implies ab \in \mathbb{Q}$, the variables $a$ and $b$ are not bound. So that is an issue there.